# Who is he? A high riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> Flies if he has feathers
>
> And swims if he has a sea
>
> Smokes if he has iron
>
> Then, abstract if he has a power

Who is he?

Comment: Is a high riddle one you wrote when you were high? One that is higher quality? Neither of those seem to apply very well here...

Comment: @NH that's not a very nice from you to say that it is not a high quality riddle. :/ But  hagfy was smart enough to see it as a clue ;)

Comment: lol, guess I'm the one that needs to get off my high <spoiler>...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Of course, he's a

> Horse

Flies if he has feathers

> Horse feathers?  That's just nonsense...
> From @osdavison, our friend the Pegasus seems likely

And swims if he has a sea

> Seahorse

Smokes if he has iron

> Iron horse is a literary term for "steam locomotive"

Then, abstract if he has a power

> Horsepower is a unit of measure, not a tangible thing

Also

> Horses are FAST (first letter of each line)

Plus, from the title

> Somebody acting superior might be told to get off their "high horse"

Comment: Ah, got there just before me! I'd got it from "abstract if he has power" and filled in the rest.

Comment: @guillau4 I wouldn't say it was too easy, but then again I was the one to solve it, so maybe it was?  =)  I think there have been many discussions on finding the right balance of difficulty in riddles (there's even one right now: How can I avoid the “Riddle-maker's Dilemma?”) and it's hard to get that just right.  I think yours was light on abstract/metaphorical side, and I felt the clues were well-crafted and led to a satisfying answer.